# PHP algorithm to find between values in varying distance

Tags: php, algorithm

I'm trying to create an algorithm that returns a price depending on number of hours. But the distance between the number of hours are varying. For example I have an array:

```
$set = [
   1 => 0.5,
   2 => 1,
   3 => 1.5,
   4 => 2,
   5 => 2.5,
   12 => 4
];

$value = 3;

end($set);

$limit = (int)key($set);

foreach($set as $v => $k) {

    // WRONG, doesn't account for varying distance
    if($value >= $v && $value <= $v) {

        if($value <= $limit) {

            return $k;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } 
}
```

The trouble is, the distance between 5 and 12 register as null. I might as well use `$value == $v` instead as the line I've marked as incorrect does anyway.

So I was wondering if there was a better way to round up to the next index in that array and return the value for it?

Cheers in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$set = array(1 => 0.5, 2 => 1, 3 => 1.5, 4 => 2, 5 => 2.5, 12 => 4);
function whatever(idx, ary){
  if(in_array(idx, array_keys(ary))){
    return ary[idx];
  }
  else{
    foreach(ary as $i => $v){
      if($i > idx){
        return $v;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
echo whatever(7, $set);
```

Comment: Ahhh brilliant, that seemed really quick, too. Thanks, folks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `$v` is a single value, so `$value >= $v && $value <= $v` is equivalent to `$value == $v`.

Instead, consider that if the loop *hasn't* ended, then the cutoff hasn't been reached yet - and a current "best price" is recorded. This requires that the keys are iterated in a well-ordered manner that can be stepped, but the logic can be updated for a descending order as well.

```
$price_chart = [
   1 => 0.5,
   2 => 1,
   3 => 1.5,
   4 => 2,
   5 => 2.5,
   12 => 4
];

function get_price ($hours) {
  global $price_chart;
  $best_price = 0;
  foreach($price_chart as $min_hours => $price) {   
    if($hours >= $min_hours) {
       // continue to next higher bracket, but remember the best price
       // which is issued for this time bracket
       $best_price = $price;
       continue;
    } else {
       // "before" the next time cut-off, $hours < $min_hours
       return $best_price;
    }
  }
  // $hours > all $min_hours
  return $best_price;
}
```

See the [ideone demo](http://ideone.com/uw8NFv). This code could also be updated to "fill in" the $price_chart, such that a price could be found simply by `$price_chart[$hours]` - but such is left as an exercise.